# how to convert milliseconds to gmt time using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project where if the end date is set for February 12 (can be set to any future date), the following is obtained from the API response.

project: {endDateTime:"1518393600000"}

For UTC time and date, this response corresponds to Mon Feb 12 2018 00:00:00

For local time and date, the response corresponds to Sun Feb 11 2018 19:00:00 (GMT - 05:00)

On the UI, I need to show the end date as Feb 12, 2018, but the date is getting converted to the local date and time zone and shows Feb 11 as the end date. My code is below:

```
var d = new Date();  
var c = d.setTime(parseInt($scope.project.endDateTime));  
$scope.endDateTime = c;
```

In the html

```
<div> {{endDateTime}} </div>
```

I tried modifying the code in the following way but it did not work.

```
 var d = new Date($scope.project.endDateTime);
 var c = d.getUTCDate();
 $scope.endDateTime = c;
```

I tried to tune the code in other ways but could not get it to work. I know similar questions have been asked before but still could not get it to work, even after spending several hours. Maybe I am missing something very trivial. Some help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `getUTCDate` gets the UTC day of month .. you're using the wrong method - maybe you want `toUTCString`

Comment: I tried d.getUTCSTring() and did a console.log(c). It shows: Invalid Date on the console.

Comment: @yugrac - I tried `var d = new Date(); d.setTime(1518393600000); d.toUTCString()` which output "Mon, 12 Feb 2018 00:00:00 GMT"

Comment: `It shows: Invalid Date on the console` - what does `console.log(d)` show? if that is an invalid date, then no date method will resurrect a proper date from bad data. Perhaps `$scope.project.endDateTime` isn't a number - what does *your original code* result in? `12`? or `Invalid Date` as well?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes you are right. I need to use this first **var d = new Date(parseInt($scope.project.endDateTime))** and then use the method **toUTCString()** . I have posted the complete code and explanation below. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. My code and explanation is as follows

```
var d = new Date(parseInt($scope.project.endDateTime));
var c = c.toUTCString();
var endDate= c.split(" ");
$scope.endDateTime = endDate[2] + ' ' + endDate[1] + ',' + ' ' + endDate[3];
```

And the html is

```
<div> {{endDateTime}}</div>
```

I needed to parse the string that came back from the API response. Missed this part and also the correct method is `toUTCString()`, not `getUTCDate()`.

So basically what happens is if the end date is set to Feb 12(in this case, it is dynamic though), the API returns

```
project: {endDateTime:"1518393600000"}
```

The first line of the code parses the string and if I do a `console.log(d)` I get this: **Sun Feb 11 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)**.

Now I need to display the time in GMT so the `toUTCString()` method was used in the second line and doing `console.log(c)` I get:  **Mon, 12 Feb 2018 00:00:00 GMT**

The requirement is to show the date as **Feb 12, 2018** on the UI, so I split the string in the third line and if i do `console.log(endDate)` I get

```
["Mon,", "12", "Feb", "2018", "00:00:00", "GMT"]
```

From the output of the third line, it was pretty easy to show the required date format. Hope this helps.